# C++ friend class of the same name in different levels of a nested namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, friend, friend-class

Not sure if this is possible, but I have two classes of the same name in different levels of a nested namespace and I'd like to make the more shallow class a friend of the deeper class. Example:

In File1.h:

```
namespace A
{
  class Foo
  {
    //stuff
  };
}
```

In File2.h:

```
namespace A
{
  namespace B
  {
    class Foo
    {
      friend class A::Foo; //Visual Studio says "Error: 'Foo' is not a member of 'A'"
    };
  }
}
```

Is this possible? If so, what is the proper syntax?

Comment: Did you include `File1.h` in `File2.h`?

Answer (score 0):

This code compiles ok when placed in one file (except that a `;` is necessary after `A::B::Foo` class): [IdeOne example](http://ideone.com/fdyAQb).

So, the issue is in the code not included in the question text. Probably `#include "File1.h"` was forgotten in `File2.h`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid including large header files into others, you need to at least forward declare your classes before using them:

```
namespace A
{
  class Foo;

  namespace B
  {
    class Foo
    {
      friend class A::Foo;
    }
  }
}
```